# Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

As you can understand from the title, I have a problem with Firebase Functions Python.

I encounter the error below.

```
Error: Failed to find the location of Firebase Functions SDK. Did you forget to run 'source /home/burak/projectFinale/functions/venv/bin/activate && python3.11 -m pip install -r requirements.txt'?
```

And also, when I want to do `firebase init functions`, it's okay until it's dependencies.

Errors below happen:

```
? Do you want to install dependencies now? Yes
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
```

I have already made the above suggestions, but the error still occurs.

I'd be glad if you help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I also encountered this error, and discovered that running `firebase deploy --only functions --debug` had the following error log towards the end: `stderr: /bin/sh: 1: source: not found`.

The reason behind this error is that `/bin/sh` points to `/bin/dash`, which does not support `source`. To resolve the issue, `/bin/sh` has to point to `/bin/bash`, which can be done by:

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash`
- Select `No`

(ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1064773/how-can-i-make-bin-sh-point-to-bin-bash)